# Cardinality of set of functions not containing a particular element

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets such that$|X|=2n$ and $|Y|=n$.

Let $a$ be a particular element of $X$. Show that the number of functions $f : Y → X$ such that $a$ is not in the image of $f$ is asymptotic to $\frac{(2n)^n}{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you find an expression for the exact number of functions?  Divide it by $(2n)^n$ and find an expression that reminds you of the definition of $e$.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of $\exp(-1/2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!2^k}$ suggests inclusion-exclusion with the $n$ properties $f(i) = a$ to be avoided:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (2n)^{n-k},$$
but this is $(2n-1)^n$ by the binomial theorem.  In hindsight, this is just the number of functions from $[n]$ to $[2n]\setminus\{a\}$.

Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^n}{(2n)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n=\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}}=\sqrt{e^{-1}}=\exp(-1/2).$$

Alternatively, the series approach yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(2n)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (2n)^{n-k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1/2)^k}{k!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} n^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1/2)^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{n-j+1}{n}\\
&\rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/2)^k}{k!}\\
&=\exp(-1/2).
\end{align}